# How to remove useless data in compiled LUA after decompiling then recompiling like with/without modifications?

Tags: lua, luac

I'm trying to compile modified LUAs with LUAC 5.1.5 but they always compile at bigger sizes than the original game files, I did exclude the compile location data already but what else? I tried every LUAC command and I still end up bigger. The game is Angry Birds Classic.

Comment: Have you tried `luac -s`, which removes debug information? Anyway, the purpose of precompiling is faster loading, not size minimization.

Comment: Yes I did that, but LUAs compiled with LUAC than compared to the game are still bigger...